# Regex to extract string between digit pattern and colon or newline

Tags: c#, regex, regex-greedy

I have to extract string between digit pattern and either a colon or newline (first occurence)

my string would look like:

> 05-30-1306-29-13                                                                                                                                                                                                                              BUILDERS RISK:
> LIMITS/DEDUCTIBLES:

I would like to extract BUILDERS RISK. There may or may not be a colon, in such case we will treat newline as the terminating pattern

Here's what I have come up with so far

```
\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s*\W+[^:|\n]+:\s*
```

Numerical pattern will always be 2-2-4-2 followed by any string followed by either \n or :

The regex so far gets what I need but I don't know how to break it into different matches so I can take the second match

> 1st match - digit pattern
>
> 2nd match - what i need
>
> 3rd match - colon or newline

Any pointers will be helpful.

**UPDATE:** Couple of alternatives of the text term to be searched could be this

> 11-06-1212-29-12  DWELLING FIRE (DP-3): ANNUAL RENTAL
>
> 11-05-1212-26-12  HOMEOWNERS (HO-3):  SECONDARY HOME

I would only want anything before colon or if that is not there, take string till newline is found. As a side note, the text of significance may not be present in same line and appear in next line but will always be followed by either a colon or newline in the same line.

PS: Extracted text should not contain colon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you may use

```
\b(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\W+(.*?)(:?\r?\n\s*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5CW%2B%28.*%3F%29%28%3A%3F%5Cr%3F%5Cn%5Cs*%29&i=05-30-1306-29-13%20BUILDERS%20RISK%3A%0D%0ALIMITS%2FDEDUCTIBLES%3A) yielding

[image]

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (change to `(?<!\d)` if the digits can be glued to a letter or underscore)
- `(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - Group 1: two digits, `-`, two digits, `-`, four digits, `-`, two digits, `-`, two digits
- `\W+` - 1+ non-word chars (to stay on the line, replace with `[^\w\r\n]+`)
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than newline, as few as possible
- `(:?\r?\n\s*)` - Group 3: an optional `:`, an optional CR, an LF symbol and then any 0+ whitespace chars.

Comment: I suppose you could also do a noncapturing group but then I also suppose the OP asked for the second group to be the interesting bit - nice RegExFu though

Comment: @Charleh I understand OP needs 3 groups, and my regex captures 3 required substrings, 1) digits, 2) `BUILDERS RISK` and 3) the colon if any and line break with any whitespace after.

Comment: Yeh, was just saying - all questions are open to interpretation and it sounds a bit like they don't actually need the other groups, just the second one (maybe they aren't aware of noncapturing groups?), but this still gives them what they need. Just an observation - I could be barking up the wrong tree

Comment: @Charleh In that case, OP might as well use `(?<=\b\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[^\w\r\n]+)[^\r\n:]+` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cb%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d%5b%5e%5cw%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%29%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%3a%5d%2b&i=05-30-1306-29-13+BUILDERS+RISK%0d%0aLIMITS%2fDEDUCTIBLES%3a%0d%0a05-30-1306-29-13+BUILDERS+RISK%3a%0d%0aLIMITS%2fDEDUCTIBLES%3a))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This regex seems to ignore the colon in the use cases i added. We should not get : with the matched text.

Comment: @user869375 So, `\b(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\W+([^:\r\n]*)(:|.*)`? See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d%29%5cW%2b%28%5b%5e%3a%5cr%5cn%5d*%29%28%3a%7c.*%29&i=05-30-1306-29-13+BUILDERS+RISK%3a%0d%0aLIMITS%2fDEDUCTIBLES%3a%0d%0a11-06-1212-29-12+DWELLING+FIRE+%28DP-3%29%3a+ANNUAL+RENTAL%0d%0a11-05-1212-26-12+HOMEOWNERS+%28HO-3%29%3a+SECONDARY+HOME%0d%0a11-05-1212-26-12+HOMEOWNERS+%28HO-3%29+SECONDARY+HOME).